# Reversal of time in solutions of autonomous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the following differential equation:

> $ y''=f(y)$  with $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and  $ a: I \to \mathbb{R}$. $a$ is the solution, which can be continued and $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous.
>
> I want to show: $ x_1 \in I$, $a'(x_1)=0 \implies a(x_1 - c)=a(x_1 + c)$  for all $c \in (I-x_1) \cup (x_1-I)$

How can I apply $a'(x_1)=0 $ in my proof?

Comment: A hint: use the uniqueness of solutions to an IVP.

Comment: The solution is unique because f is locally Lipschitz continuous. I don't know how this might help?

Comment: Sub-hint: If $y:x\mapsto a(x_1+x)$ solves $y''=f(y)$ then $y:x\mapsto a(x_1-x)$ solves $y''=\ldots$

Comment: I would say:...solves $ y''=f(y).$

Comment: Can somebody explain how I can proof that?